# Stylet Button not enabling when its CanX property returns true

Tags: c#, wpf, stylet

Using [Stylet](https://github.com/canton7/Stylet)

I'm using the default Stylet template with dotnet core 3.1.
I simply added a property/method for reproducing the issue.

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Username, 
                Mode=TwoWay, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         Width="100" Height="100"/>

<Button Command="{s:Action Do}">Foo</Button>
```

```cs
public class ShellViewModel : Screen
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public void Do() { }

    public bool CanDo => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Username);
}
```

Breakpoint on `CanDo` property is hit once and never hit again. Changing the value in the `TextBox`, while calling `set`, does not retrigger the `CanDo` property.

I've also tried using backing fields with `SetAndNotify`, to no avail:

```cs
public string Username { get => username; set => SetAndNotify(ref username, value, nameof(Username)); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize I am missing property changed notifications. Through all of the examples I saw I assumed this was handled implicitly by Stylet for me.

After changing my property setters to the following, it works as expected.

```cs
public string Username
{
    get => _username;
    set
    {
        SetAndNotify(ref _username, value);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanLogin);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> PropertyChangedBase also takes care to integrate with Fody.PropertyChanged. Notifications raised by Fody.PropertyChanged are raised using the PropertyChangedDispatcher.
>
> Therefore you do not need to do anything special in order to use Fody.PropertyChanged with any subclass of Screen, ValidatingModelBase, or PropertyChangedBase.

This is from the Stylet Document wiki. If a project is using Fody.PropertyChanged, then it don't have to write the NotifyOfPropertyChange() manually, maybe that's why you didn't see NotifyOfPropertyChange() in the sample codes.

Fody.PropertyChanged is a wonderful package, try it, it saves me millions of keystrokes :)